# Custom http client when using google's java adwords client library?

Tags: java, sdk, apache-httpclient-4.x, google-ads-api

I'm using google's java [client library](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib) to create adwords campaigns. This works fine during development, but when I deploy my service to production, all our outgoing requests need to pass through our own proxy. Our proxy examines some of our custom http headers and forwards the request to the Internet. My questions are:
 1. is it possible to use my own custom http client instead of the one that ships with the library to make the http request ?
 2. in case 1. is not possible, is it possible to add custom http headers to the requests made by the client?

(I have looked at the source code and have determined that there is no obvious way to plug in my own http client, and would be pleased to be proven wrong. :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sdk doesn't support it at the moment, the workaround is to use the `proxySelector` and add custom logic there.
  [docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html)